# Eclipse java Debugger Class structure for dynamically generated classes

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Newbie question-

I have classes that are generated at load-time by the spring container (proxies for supporting aop) and I wanted to know if there is a way to examine the class structure using the eclipse debugger (or otherwise without writing code). Right now, the stack shows the method call and the text `"line: not available [local variables unavailable]"` and the editor shows `"Source not found."` I wanted to find out things about the class structure: e.g. if the class is final or not, what is the visibility of its methods, etc.

Thanks in advance!